# Counting unique list items

Tags: r, list, dataframe, data.table, aggregate

Assuming I have a datatable `dt.recipes` which consists of lists with various items, for example:

```
recipe_id     ingredients
1             apple, banana, cucumber, water
2             apple, meat, water
3             water
```

How can I create a table, counting the amount of *unique* items present in `dt.recipes$ingredients`? In other words, I am looking for a result similar to this:

```
ingredient    count
water         3
apple         2
banana        1
cucumber      1
meat          1
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `data.table` way could be

```
library(data.table)
dt[, .(table(unlist(ingredients)))]
#         V1 N
#1:    apple 2
#2:   banana 1
#3: cucumber 1
#4:     meat 1
#5:    water 3
```

**data**

```
dt <- data.table(
  "recipe_id" = 1:3,
  "ingredients" = list(
    c("apple", "banana", "cucumber", "water"),
    c("apple", "meat", "water"),
    c("water")
  )
)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```r
 as.data.frame(table(unlist(strsplit(df$ingredients, ", "))))
#>       Var1 Freq
#> 1    apple    2
#> 2   banana    1
#> 3 cucumber    1
#> 4     meat    1
#> 5    water    3
```

---

**Data**

```r
df <- structure(list(recipe_id = 1:3, 
               ingredients = c("apple, banana, cucumber, water", 
                               "apple, meat, water", 
                               "water")), 
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df
#>   recipe_id                    ingredients
#> 1         1 apple, banana, cucumber, water
#> 2         2             apple, meat, water
#> 3         3                          water
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

With functions from `tidyverse`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  separate_rows(ingredients) %>% 
  count(ingredients, name = "count") %>% 
  arrange(desc(count))

# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  ingredients count
#  <chr>       <int>
#1 water           3
#2 apple           2
#3 banana          1
#4 cucumber        1
#5 meat            1
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option with `scan` + `table` + `as.data.frame`

```
> with(df, as.data.frame(table(trimws(scan(text = ingredients, what = "", sep = ",", quiet = TRUE)))))
      Var1 Freq
1    apple    2
2   banana    1
3 cucumber    1
4     meat    1
5    water    3
```